# Is there a way to get a report of Landing Pages in Google Ads via the Google Ads API, Scripts or BigQuery Data Transfer Service?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api, google-ads-script

I am currently in the process of creating an overview of ad spent per landing page/destination url.
We are using several campaign types:

- Shopping
- (Responsive) Search Ads
- Dynamic Search Ads

I am struggling to get a report per landingpage for each campaign type. We have multiple Customer Ids and I would need data for all Customer Ids. When looking at the Google Ads API documentation I think I would need these two reports to get all I need

- Keywordless Query Report (for Dynamic Search Ads landing pages): https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/keywordless-query-report
- Landing Page Report (for Shopping and (responsive) search ads landing pages): https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/landing-page-report

Ideally, the data would be uploaded to a BigQuery dataset.

What I have tried:
I have set up a BigQuery Data Transfer (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/adwords-transfer). This contains a lot of reports but not the two reports listed above.

I have tried a Google Ads script, but my knowledge of that is too little to write a script that woudl give the same/similar results as the two reports listed above. Next to that I would need help getting this data in my BigQuery project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

There is a Google Ads Script which requires minimum adjustments to fulfill my needs:
Single Account: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/solutions/bigquery-exporter

Manager Account: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/solutions/adsmanagerapp-bigquery-exporter

I simply had to change the:

- BIGQUERY_PROJECT_ID
- BIGQUERY_DATASET_ID
- list of reports (I only needed "LANDING_PAGE_REPORT")